# Minimum set of specialities to cover most medical needs

Tags: science-based, medicine, medical

I'm writing a fictional story and there is an eccentric billionaire who has his own personal staff of medical personnel. What would be some specialities to consider to include in this group. He is a ~300 billionaire so money isn't a big issue. For example he would have his own mri machine, his own OR. His own lab for most blood work.

For example based on my research, a trauma surgeon also trained in cardio and with access to cardiopulmonary bypass, and a Neuro surgeon could cover alot of cases for immediate surgery. I think we would need an anesthesiologist, but based on memes they don't seem to do alot of active work and so maybe a very skilled nurse can fill that role (legality aside)

Is there ideally 4-6 core medical specialities that would cover alot from a physicians pov. Maybe some of those doctors have multiple specialities?

Comment: Need the age, gender and underlying medical conditions of the billionaire and any dependents that need to be catered for.  There are 80+ recognised specialties, but some relate to particular age groups, genders and/or conditions

Comment: Let's say 40-50. But other than that nothing specific yet.

Comment: What's your definition of "most medical needs"? We've been treating injuries and sickness for tens of thousands of years. Throughout that time our definition of most medical needs has constantly been changing.

Comment: What does a 40-50 year old (with no underlying conditions) need with his own army of medical specialists?

Comment: I'm not sure unfortunately with what I mean by most. It's not that he can't consult or see other doctors that are specialists in certain cases, but that this team would manage his over all care in all cases and can directly handle all emergency and holistic health needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**4+ cross-trained geniuses**

Here's a tentative list of the specialties that may be needed to cover routine care and any moderately foreseeable emergency.  In real life few doctors are able to remain current in more than two specialties, however, it may be plausible for doctors who can spend most of their time studying rather than practising to keep themselves current in 3 of the below specialties.  (They probably should be practising on the billionaire's other staff in order to retain some kind of practical currency.)

**Routine care and diagnosis:**

- General practitioner
- Pharmacist
- Pathologist (general)
- Diagnostic radiology
- Diagnostic ultrasound
- Physiotherapist
- Optometrist
- Psychiatrist
- Dentist

**Emergency and surgery:**

- Anaesthetist
- General surgery
- Emergency physician
- Intensive care specialist

It is critical that the last 4 specialties are secondary/tertiary specialties of different people - a team of 3-4 people is the absolute minimum for any kind of surgery under anaesthetic.

This is ignoring not just the specialties that definitely don't apply (the various paediatric and obs/gyn areas, since the pronoun indicates that the billionaire is male) but also 20+ specialist disciples such as cardiologists, neurologists, orthopaedic surgeons etc.  Hopefully the general surgeon can study up on any specialty surgeries that are required, although the billionaire should be nervous about being operated on by a "hobby" neurosurgeon / plastic surgeon / cardio-thoracic surgeon.  The medical staff should also push the billionaire to allow them to consult remotely with specialists in other fields not covered if anything comes up.

EDIT:  I forgot dentists!  It is also important that doctors normally rely on nurses / technicians to do a lot of the actual work, these specialists will also need to do the grunt work.  For example diagnostic radiologists almost never take X-rays themselves, they just analyze the results.

Comment: Thanks! This was a great answer